# button clickable only with a stylus

Tags: android, button, motionevent

I have a button that I would like clickable only by a stylus.
I used the method setClickable to enable or disable the click on the button, but how can I do that is clickable only with a pen? 
the button should be clickable only when MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS

how do i can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could override the `Button`'s `onTouchListener`, and return immediately it the touch event is not performed through `TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS`. To retrieve this information, you can use

```
getToolType(int pointerX)
```

From the documentation

> Gets the tool type of a pointer for the given pointer index

if it returns `TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS`, then you can simply check the `MotionEvent` for the `ACTION_DOWN`/`ACTION_UP`, and call `performClick()`. E.g.

```
b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getToolType(0) == MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
                    performClick();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: and how do I handle the setOnClickListener ?what can i write the performclick()?

Comment: `performClick` is a method of View. it calls onClick, if there is an OnClickListener attached