# Disabling touch input while writing with digital pen / stylus

Tags: android

The whole idea of what I'm doing is, creating a notebook use case, where we can have n pages.
Now, I have used RecyclerView and added the item adapter,  using the complete screen as a single item for writing.

Now, whenever I start writing on the view which is the property for HW acceleration, I got events but the recycler adapter thinks differently.

How do I solve this? I would like to make sure when writing is happening using a digital pen, the adapter should ignore it, and when we do finger swipe it should move to the next screen/page.

Comment: Does it work with the setOnTouchListener?

Comment: I will get back to you on this, overall I need more control, like while writing in the view , I don't need swipe, but when I'm using finger only I need swipe and also, there is a case when writing using digital pen, there is a chance to get both as we might be pressing withour hand on the screen while writing, and also, just before swiping to next page I need to save the present page, some house keeping

Answer (score 0):

You can use a setOnTouchListener to differentiate between the events. check this links out from SO:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745599/button-clickable-only-with-a-stylus) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418510/disable-the-touch-events-for-all-the-views) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239992/disabling-touch-in-android-only-allowing-stylus)